# Android - Make sure activity is alive before firing Intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am currently firing an Intent to a Broadcast Receiver which in turns starts an Activity.

Then from the same Service another Intent is fired to a Broadcast Receiver thats in the Activity.

The problem is that the Activity isn't getting the Intent meant for it because it is fired before it is alive and the Broadcast Reciever is registered.

I was wondering is there anyway to make sure an Activity is alive before sending an Intent?

Or any other solution to this?

Comment: I thought I had this fixed but the issue has arisen again. Has anyone an example of how to use a sendOrderedBroadcast? and get data back?

Comment: this is the best example of sendOrderedBroadcast() i've found... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943386/android-sendorderedbroadcast-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start the activity if it is not yet alive?

> The general mechanism to start a new
>   activity if its not running— or to
>   bring the activity stack to the front
>   if is already running in the
>   background— is the to use the
>   NEW_TASK_LAUNCH flag in the
>   startActivity() call.

That or simply give the activity a chance to start before firing the Intent.

Alternatively you could try using [sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to retrieve data back from the broadcast and then possibly do a retry.

```
public abstract void sendOrderedBroadcast (Intent intent, String receiverPermission, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras)
```

Comment: I thought I had this fixed but the issue has arisen again. Has anyone an example of how to use a sendOrderedBroadcast? and get data back?