# Android - sendOrderedBroadcast help

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a [sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.os.Handler,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) in my Android app.

I want to be able to send the Intent from one of my applications to another and I then want to get data back from the Application that recieves the Intent, in this case a boolean true or false.

Here is the current code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(GlobalData.PROPOSE_IN_DOMAIN_ROAM_INTENT);
    i.putExtra("com.testnetworks.QCLEVEL", aProposedTheoreticalQoSLevel);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null, null, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Is this the correct way to achieve what I want?

If so what do I use as the resultReceiver* parameter? (3rd parameter)

And then how to I recieve data back from the Broadcast?

I have done a quick google and not come up with any examples, any help or examples greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE:**

---

```
sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null, domainBroadcast, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

---

```
class DomainBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(GlobalData.PROPOSE_IN_DOMAIN_ROAM_INTENT.equals(action)){
            Log.d("BROADCAST", "Returning broadcast");

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras(); 
            Log.d("BROADCAST", "Returning broadcast " + 
                    b.getInt("com.testnetworks.INT_TEST"));
        }      
    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction(); 

            if(GlobalData.PROPOSE_IN_DOMAIN_ROAM_INTENT.equals(action)){

                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                int testQCLevel = b.getInt("com.testnetworks.QCLEVEL");
                switch(testQCLevel){
                case 1:
                    Log.d("QCLevel ", "QCLevel = UNAVAILABLE");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d("QCLevel ", "QCLevel = BELOWUSABILITY");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d("QCLevel ", "QCLevel = VOICE");
                    break;
                }

                intent.putExtra("com.testnetworks.INT_TEST", 100);

          }
```

---

So according to the Doc's I should recieve 100 back in my DomainBroadcast reciever but it always comes back as 0.

Can anyone see why?

**resultReceiver - Your own BroadcastReceiver to treat as the final receiver of the broadcast.*

Comment: You have two `onReceive()` methods above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You need to [get the extra data results Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#getResultExtras%28boolean%29) and  add your data to it.**

Try something like this:

```
public class DemoOrderedBroadcast extends Activity {
    private static String SOMETHING_HAPPENED = "com.example.somethinghappened";
    private static String EXTRA_INTEGER = "extra integer";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SOMETHING_HAPPENED);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
                results.putInt(EXTRA_INTEGER, 100);
                Log.d("DemoOrderedBroadcast",
                        "In Initial Receiver: Put 'extra integer' = 100");
            }
        }, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SOMETHING_HAPPENED);
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
                Log.d("DemoOrderedBroadcast",
                        "In Result Receiver: Got 'extra integer' = "
                                + results.getInt(EXTRA_INTEGER, -1));
            }
        }, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
}
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
$ adb -e shell am start -n com.example.DemoOrderedBroadcast/.DemoOrderedBroadcast
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.DemoOrderedBroadcast/.DemoOrderedBroadcast }
$ adb -e shell logcat | grep D/DemoOrderedBroadcast
D/DemoOrderedBroadcast( 1343): In Initial Receiver: Put 'extra integer' = 100
D/DemoOrderedBroadcast( 1343): In Result Receiver: Got 'extra integer' = 100
```

Comment: How would this work if you had two broadcast receivers. In an example I have running, the incoming receiver only gets triggered once.